# An error ocurring which RangError(index): Invalid Value:Not in inclusive Range 0..4.5

Tags: flutter

```
I am building a dashboard application in which menu should have at least 6 icons.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hexcolor/hexcolor.dart';


class HomePageScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  List catNames = [
    "Category",
    "Event",
    "Venue",
    "Map",
    "Decoration",
    "Others",
  ];

  List catColors = [
    Color(0xff687EFF),
    Color(0xff687EFF),
    Color(0xff687EFF),
    Color(0xff687EFF),
    Color(0xff687EFF),
  ];

  List catIcons = [
    Icon(Icons.category, color: HexColor("#ffffff"), size: 30),
    Icon(Icons.event, color: HexColor("#ffffff"), size: 30),
    Icon(Icons.room, color: HexColor("#ffffff"), size: 30),
    Icon(Icons.map, color: HexColor("#ffffff"), size: 30),
    Icon(Icons.deck, color: HexColor("#ffffff"), size: 30),
    Icon(Icons.home_mini, color: HexColor("#ffffff"), size: 30),
  ];
```

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 15, right: 15, bottom: 10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: HexColor("#687EFF"),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
                )
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Icon(
                      Icons.dashboard,
                      size: 30,
                      color: HexColor("#ffffff"),
                    ),
                    Icon(
                      Icons.notifications_active,
                      size: 30,
                      color: HexColor("#ffffff"),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 3, bottom: 15),
                  child: Text(
                    "Hi, Customer Name",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 25,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      fontFamily: "poppins_bold",
                      wordSpacing: 2,
                      letterSpacing: 1,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 20),
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: 55,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: HexColor("#ffffff"),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.5),
                  ),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: "Search here...",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                      ),
                      prefixIcon: Icon(
                        Icons.search,
                        size: 25,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 15, right: 15),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                GridView.builder(
                  itemCount: catNames.length,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 3,
                    childAspectRatio: 1.1,
                  ),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          height: 50,
                          width: 50,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: catColors[index],
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          ),
                          child: Center(
                            child: catIcons[index],
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                        Text(
                          catNames[index],
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontFamily: "poppins_bold",
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

An error occurring which [RangError(index): Invalid Value:Not in inclusive Range 0..4.5. I am facing error. I have tried every way to solve this but it is not resolving. If someone know where the problems and have solution then please elaborate.

Whenever i tried to run the application 5 icons are working and set correctly but last icon is showing error of this
RangError(index): Invalid Value:Not in inclusive Range 0..4.5

Answer (score 0):

You have 6 elements in "catNames", and you use

```
 GridView.builder(
              itemCount: catNames.length,
  ......)
```

but you use "catColors[index]", in that list you have 5 elements. It should render 6 elements, but when it seeks the catColors[5], it does not exist.

```
List catColors = [
Color(0xff687EFF),
Color(0xff687EFF),
Color(0xff687EFF),
Color(0xff687EFF),
Color(0xff687EFF),  <-- this is the catColors[4]
```

];
You use the same color, you could only change the color in that place:

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
     color: Color(0xff687EFF) <-//catColors[index], 
     shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      ),
```

or add a new color, in the list.